No DNS connection from docker container to host network
I'm running a Debian 12 VM with pihole+unbound (version v5.18.3) and docker (version 20.10.24) installed. When I'm inside a docker container and run "curl gitlab.my.domain" which should resolve to my local GitLab instance through my pihole, but I got the following error:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:
and dig responds with
communications error to 10.0.0.3#53: timed out
On any other host in the network including the VM itself the DNS request work perfectly. All other container on different hosts don't have that problem. The port is open, and pi hole is running normal. Even the resolv.conf inside the docker container got an entry "nameserver 10.0.0.3". The container got a connection to the host network, since in responds to the default Placeholder page. I'm at the end of my tether. What have I missed?

The firewall settings in the pihole were set incorrectly (Respond only on interface eth0).
How the problem was solved:
Settings > DNS > Interface Settings > Permit all origins
Now it resolves in the docker container as well.
